# Waiting for multiple observable to complete that return different number of elements

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

Scenario: I have a customerID string that is used to query multiple different backend systems: calendar, helpdesk, ERP, CRM etc. I want to compile a single report.
So I have roughly (psydocode):

```
Result myResult = new Result();
Observable<Cal> cal = Calbackend.get(customerid);
cal.subscribe(calentry -> myResult.addCal(calentry));

Observable<Erp> erp = ERPbackend.get(customerid);
erp.subscribe(erpentry -> myResult.addErp(erpentry));

Observable<Help> help = Helpbackend.get(customerid);
help.subscribe(helpentry -> myResult.addHelp(helpentry));

Observable<Crm> crm = CRMbackend.get(customerid);
crm.subscribe(crmentry -> myResult.addCrm(crmentry));

// Magic here?

return result;
```

The approach I was thinking of: using `defer()` to prevent the start and then additionally subscribe to `count()` for each. Then I could ZIP the count elements since they only will emit a single item each (while the others will have different numbers of events). However that could lead to loss of data if the `myResult.add` is performing slower than the `count()`.

The other option I was thinking of, is to set an array of boolean flags for each subscription and check in each completion (and error) event if all of them are done and do a callback or use blocking for that one.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517589/wait-for-multiple-async-calls-to-finish-in-rxjava) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289093/how-to-wait-for-async-observable-to-complete) but that examples deal with constant numbers or data types.

Or is there a better / recommended way?

Comment: Do you expect more than one emission from these Observables? If yes, you could use the `toList` operator, that compiles all the emitted items to a list and emits it, when the source Observable completes. Then you could just zip all those 4 Observables emitting lists together and compose your Result.

Comment: Yes. Each observable has an unknown number of emissions. The numbers are not related. The toList operator does return a list that keeps the insertion order? Turn your comment into an answer for acceptance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator `toList` can be used together with `zip` like this:

```
Observable<List<Cal>> cal = Calbackend.get(customerid).toList();
Observable<List<Erp>> erp = ERPbackend.get(customerid).toList();
Observable<List<Help>> help = Helpbackend.get(customerid).toList();
Observable<List<Crm>> crm = CRMbackend.get(customerid).toList();
Observable.zip(cal, erp, help, crm,
                new Func4<List<Cal>, List<Erp>, List<Help>, List<Crm>, Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public Result call(List<Cal> cals, List<Erp> erps, List<Help> helps, List<Crm> crms) {
                        Result myResult = new Result();
                        // add all cals, erps, helps and crms to result
                        return myResult;
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Result result) {
                        // do something with the result
                    }

                    ...
                });
```

**Explanation:** As the name suggests, the `toList` operator creates a list of the items emitted by the source observable (the list is emitted just once, when the source observable completes) and `zip` is then used to combine the results of the observables.

**Edit:** In case of the possibility that those Observables can emit an error, you could use `onErrorReturn` to keep the normal flow going:

```
Observable<List<Cal>> cal = Calbackend.get(customerid)
            .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, Cal>() {
                @Override
                public Cal call(Throwable throwable) {
                    // Return something in the error case
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .toList();
```

Comment: Thx. Now I need to evaluate the .toList() behaviour in error cases. Like I get 5 elements and then an error. Will I get no list or the good ones - but that's best put into a new question.